# Powerline adapter to connect 2 apartments in one building?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Let’s say a have a friend of mine living in the same building just say 20 meters away from me. And he has home internet but wlan is to week to reach my apartment is there a easy way to connect to his internet? Using powerrline adapter I heard it has to be on the same circuit but I don’t think the 2 apartment have same circuit ? So what is a good way to connect to his internet? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All legal arguments against doing this aside, I doubt that a powerline adapter is what you want here.

You will probably have better results with a "Wifi Range Extender" or a Wifi Repeater.  There are many suitable products on the market and some simple searching or a trip to a local electronics/computer products store should net you one.

In extreme cases, you might consider a directional-gain antenna that, in some cases, can extend the range from a few dozen meters to a km or more depending on terrain and conditions.

Answer (score 1):

PLA can't transmit between poles of a transformer. But typically, most apartments have both poles available.  Any given circuit is punched down onto one of them.  So you have a 50/50 chance that he puts the PLA onto the same pole as you do.  If it doesn't work, you can try different circuits until you find the same pole.

However, there is a lot of wiring complexity between different apartments, and that may attenuate the signal too much to be useful.

I agree wireless may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If there is line-of-sight between the two buildings, buy a pair of point-to-point Wi-Fi bridges. (For example, NanoStation or LigoDLB would work up to ~10 km.)

They might cost you some $200 but from my experience they provide a *very* reliable connection. Point them at each other correctly and you'll get stable 100 Mbps for years.

At close distances, under 1 km, just one bridge might be enough (at your house and pointed at neighbour's normal Wi-Fi router).